# cascade not working with hibernate @Any

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate's @Any(one to any) annotation in my java code. Below here'a a code snippet:

```
@Entity
public class A {
//.. few properties

@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "type"), fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string", metaValues = {@MetaValue(targetEntity = Http.class, value = "http")})
@JoinColumn(name = "protocol_id")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Protocol protocol;

//more code

}
```

Now when I update the field using session.update(a) where a is an instance of A, a new record for field protocol is created and the earlier one is not deleted. Desired result was that old record for field protocol gets deleted when I update using session.update(a) and new record gets created .  Since I am using cascadeType ALL, why is this not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to annotate with @OneToOne or @ManyToOne as needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be great if you could expand on your answer and explain why the OP should try those annotations out.